# Mathematical Induction Problem from Concrete Abstractions

Tags: induction, lisp

This is a problem from 'Concrete Abstractions' which is available free on the web[1]. It's a book similar to SICP. The problem:

> Exercise 2.16
>      Consider the following procedure foo:

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x n)
    (if (= n 0)
        1
        (+ (expt x n) (foo x (- n 1))))))
```

> Use induction to prove that `(foo x n)` terminates with the value
>           $$\frac{x^{n + 1} - 1 } {x - 1}$$
>
> for all values of x != 1 and for all integers n >= 0. You may assume that `expt` works
>      correctly, (i.e., `(expt b m)` returns $b^m$). Hint: The inductive step will involve some algebra.

I've watched a video on induction on Khan Academy and read the induction material in the book, but I can't connect the dots to solve this problem.

Edit:
I am stuck at the Inductive step. My work:
Base Case:

```
(foo x 0)
(if (= n 0)
    1)
```

returns $1$ and

$\frac{x^{0+1} - 1} {x - 1} = \frac{x - 1}{x - 1} = 1$

So for the inductive hypothesis: Assume `(foo x k)` terminates in $\frac{x^{k+1} - 1}{x - 1}$ for all $k \geq 0$. Then for $k+1$:
I essentially add $k+1$ for the assumed formula above, so:
$\frac{x^{k+1} - 1}{x - 1} + k+1$. What I get is a long equation that I have no idea what to do with.

Comment: Where do you get stuck?  Are you able to work out by hand what this function does for $n=1$ and $x\neq 1$?

Comment: Louis: Sorry, I should have mentioned this. I am fine with the base case n = 0. And I think I understand the inductive hypothesis. It's the Inductive Step. I will edit the original post explaining this / my work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your induction step is recorded incorrectly.

You wrote:

$$\frac{x^{k+1} - 1}{x - 1} + k+1$$

You should have written:

$$\frac{x^{k+1} - 1}{x - 1} + x^{k+1}$$

Basically, you are proving the formula for the sum of the geometric sequence.

Comment: That makes sense. I was confused by an example problem. Thank you!